# How to access underlying express app in Keystone 6?

Tags: javascript, express, keystonejs

I'm using Keystone 6 for my backend and I'm trying to integrate Stripe, which requires access to the underlying express app to pass a client secret to the client from the server. This is highlighted in the Stripe documentation here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents#passing-to-client

I'm having trouble figuring out how to access the express app in Keystone 6 though and they don't seem to mention anything about this in the documentation. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is Keystone 6 doesn't support this yet.

The longer answer has two parts:

**This functionality is coming**

We've been discussing this requirement internally and the priority of it has been raised. We're updating the public roadmap to reflect this next week.
The functionality itself should arrive soon after. (Unfortunately I can't commit to a release date.)

**Getting access to the Express app is *possible*, it's just a real pain right now**

If you look at Keystone's `start` command you can see where it
[calls `createExpressServer()`](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/d214e2f72bae1c798e2415a38410d6063c333e2e/packages/keystone/src/scripts/run/start.ts#L30).
This just returns an express app with the GraphQL API and a few other bits and bobs.
But there's actually nothing forcing you to use the build in `keystone start` command – You can copy this code, hack it up and just run it directly yourself.

Eg. you could replace this...

```js
const server = await createExpressServer(
  config,
  graphQLSchema,
  keystone.createContext,
  false,
  getAdminPath(cwd)
);
```

With...

```js
const server = express();
server.get('/hello-world', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello');
});

const keystoneServer = await createExpressServer(
  config,
  graphQLSchema,
  keystone.createContext,
  false,
  getAdminPath(cwd)
);
server.use(keystoneServer);
```

And your `/hello-world` endpoint should take precedence over the stuff Keystone adds.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work for the `dev` command so, in your local environment you'll need to do it differently.

One option is to start a second express server that you control and put it on a different port and include your custom routes there.
You can still do this from within your Keystone app codebase but having different URLs in different environments can be annoying.
You'll probably need an environment variable just for your custom endpoints URL, with values like this in production:

```sh
# Production
GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT="https://api.example.com/api/graphql"
CUSTOM_ENDPOINT="https://api.example.com/hello-world"
```

And this in dev:

```sh
# Dev
GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:3000/api/graphql"
CUSTOM_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:3100/hello-world"
```

It's ugly but it does work.

I'll update this answer when the "official" functionality lands.

Comment: Cheers, thanks for the detailed answer. Looking forward to the finished Keystone 6.

Comment: The latest release of Keystone 6 (https://keystonejs.com/releases/2021-07-29) now lets you add routes for custom Next.js pages (https://keystonejs.com/docs/guides/custom-admin-ui-pages). Note, this doesn't give you "access to the underlying express app" – so doesn't address the Stripe webhook problem posed by the original questions – but it does help for some related use cases. Being able to add arbitrary routes at the Express level is still in progress.